# Cómo sacar una alerta cuando varios elementos se alinean en el código de esta pregunta?

Tags: javascript, jquery

He estado intentando crear una alerta cuando los siguientes #div se muestran a la vez:

- layer0_1
- layer1_1
- layer2_1
- layer3_1
- layer4_1
- layer5_1
  Sé que os resultará sencillo pero no sé por qué me esta presentando tantísimos problemas, seguro que es un error muy básico.

```js
$(this).ready(function() 
{  
   if ($('#layer0_1').is(':visible')) 
   {
alert(new Date());
   }
    
});

function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo, inicial) {
  var $els = $('div[id^=' + selector + ']'),
      i = inicial,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.not( ':eq('+i+')' ).hide(); /*Ocultamos los que no sean el inicial */
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
   $("#layer6_").text($els.eq(i).attr('id'));
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
  }, tiempo)
}

jQuery(function() {
  /* Este sería el número que debería proporcionar el código del lado del servidor, 
   por ejemplo en PHP: round(microtime(true) * 1000)*/
   var startdate = " May 20 2016 21:49:57 GMT+0200  ", 
   timestamp =  new Date() - new Date(startdate) ;

  mostrarEsconder('layer0_', 300,  Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 11),
  mostrarEsconder('layer1_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 12),
  mostrarEsconder('layer2_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 13),
  mostrarEsconder('layer3_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 14),
  mostrarEsconder('layer4_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 15),
  mostrarEsconder('layer5_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 30);
});
```

```css
.numero {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  left: 20px;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  left: 20px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero3 {
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  left: 20px;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero4 {
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  left: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero5 {
  position: absolute;
  color: cyan;
  left: 20px;
  top: 120px;
  z-index: 500; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer0_1">
<div class="numero">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_2">
<div class="numero">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_3">
<div class="numero">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_4">
<div class="numero">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_5">
<div class="numero">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_6">
<div class="numero">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_7">
<div class="numero">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_8">
<div class="numero">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_9">
<div class="numero">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_10">
<div class="numero">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_11">
<div class="numero">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_1">
<div class="numero1">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_2">
<div class="numero1">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_3">
<div class="numero1">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_4">
<div class="numero1">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_5">
<div class="numero1">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_6">
<div class="numero1">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_7">
<div class="numero1">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_8">
<div class="numero1">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_9">
<div class="numero1">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_10">
<div class="numero1">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_11">
<div class="numero1">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_12">
<div class="numero1">12</div>
</div>

<div id="layer2_1">
<div class="numero2">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_2">
<div class="numero2">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_3">
<div class="numero2">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_4">
<div class="numero2">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_5">
<div class="numero2">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_6">
<div class="numero2">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_7">
<div class="numero2">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_8">
<div class="numero2">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_9">
<div class="numero2">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_10">
<div class="numero2">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_11">
<div class="numero2">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_12">
<div class="numero2">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_13">
<div class="numero2">13</div>
</div>

<div id="layer3_1">
<div class="numero3">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_2">
<div class="numero3">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_3">
<div class="numero3">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_4">
<div class="numero3">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_5">
<div class="numero3">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_6">
<div class="numero3">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_7">
<div class="numero3">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_8">
<div class="numero3">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_9">
<div class="numero3">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_10">
<div class="numero3">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_11">
<div class="numero3">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_12">
<div class="numero3">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_13">
<div class="numero3">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_14">
<div class="numero3">14</div>
</div>

<div id="layer4_1">
<div class="numero4">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_2">
<div class="numero4">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_3">
<div class="numero4">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_4">
<div class="numero4">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_5">
<div class="numero4">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_6">
<div class="numero4">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_7">
<div class="numero4">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_8">
<div class="numero4">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_9">
<div class="numero4">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_10">
<div class="numero4">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_11">
<div class="numero4">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_12">
<div class="numero4">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_13">
<div class="numero4">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_14">
<div class="numero4">14</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_15">
<div class="numero4">15</div>
</div>

<div id="layer5_1">
<div class="numer5">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_2">
<div class="numer5">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_3">
<div class="numer5">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_4">
<div class="numer5">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_5">
<div class="numer5">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_6">
<div class="numer5">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_7">
<div class="numer5">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_8">
<div class="numer5">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_9">
<div class="numer5">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_10">
<div class="numer5">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_11">
<div class="numer5">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_12">
<div class="numer5">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_13">
<div class="numer5">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_14">
<div class="numer5">14</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_15">
<div class="numero5">15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Que elemento selecionas con el ready osea $(this).ready(function(){}}); no deberia ser $(document).ready(function(){}});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay ningún evento que se genere tras mostrarse u ocultarse un elemento por lo que deberías ejecutar esta comprobación cada vez que muestres un elemento:

```js
function checkVisible()
{  
  if ($('#layer0_1').is(':visible') &&
      $('#layer1_1').is(':visible')) 
  {
    alert(new Date());
  }

};

function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo, inicial) {
  var $els = $('div[id^=' + selector + ']'),
      i = inicial,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.not( ':eq('+i+')' ).hide(); /*Ocultamos los que no sean el inicial */
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
      $("#layer6_").text($els.eq(i).attr('id'));
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0, checkVisible);
    })
  }, tiempo)
}

jQuery(function() {
  /* Este sería el número que debería proporcionar el código del lado del servidor, 
       por ejemplo en PHP: round(microtime(true) * 1000)*/
  var startdate = " May 20 2016 21:49:57 GMT+0200  ", 
      timestamp =  new Date() - new Date(startdate) ;

  mostrarEsconder('layer0_', 300,  Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 11),
    mostrarEsconder('layer1_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 12),
    mostrarEsconder('layer2_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 13),
    mostrarEsconder('layer3_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 14),
    mostrarEsconder('layer4_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 15),
    mostrarEsconder('layer5_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 30);
});
```

```css
.numero {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  left: 20px;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  left: 20px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero3 {
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  left: 20px;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero4 {
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  left: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero5 {
  position: absolute;
  color: cyan;
  left: 20px;
  top: 120px;
  z-index: 500; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer0_1">
  <div class="numero">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_2">
  <div class="numero">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_3">
  <div class="numero">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_4">
  <div class="numero">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_5">
  <div class="numero">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_6">
  <div class="numero">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_7">
  <div class="numero">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_8">
  <div class="numero">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_9">
  <div class="numero">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_10">
  <div class="numero">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_11">
  <div class="numero">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_1">
  <div class="numero1">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_2">
  <div class="numero1">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_3">
  <div class="numero1">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_4">
  <div class="numero1">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_5">
  <div class="numero1">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_6">
  <div class="numero1">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_7">
  <div class="numero1">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_8">
  <div class="numero1">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_9">
  <div class="numero1">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_10">
  <div class="numero1">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_11">
  <div class="numero1">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_12">
  <div class="numero1">12</div>
</div>

<div id="layer2_1">
  <div class="numero2">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_2">
  <div class="numero2">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_3">
  <div class="numero2">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_4">
  <div class="numero2">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_5">
  <div class="numero2">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_6">
  <div class="numero2">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_7">
  <div class="numero2">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_8">
  <div class="numero2">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_9">
  <div class="numero2">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_10">
  <div class="numero2">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_11">
  <div class="numero2">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_12">
  <div class="numero2">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_13">
  <div class="numero2">13</div>
</div>

<div id="layer3_1">
  <div class="numero3">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_2">
  <div class="numero3">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_3">
  <div class="numero3">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_4">
  <div class="numero3">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_5">
  <div class="numero3">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_6">
  <div class="numero3">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_7">
  <div class="numero3">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_8">
  <div class="numero3">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_9">
  <div class="numero3">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_10">
  <div class="numero3">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_11">
  <div class="numero3">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_12">
  <div class="numero3">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_13">
  <div class="numero3">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_14">
  <div class="numero3">14</div>
</div>

<div id="layer4_1">
  <div class="numero4">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_2">
  <div class="numero4">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_3">
  <div class="numero4">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_4">
  <div class="numero4">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_5">
  <div class="numero4">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_6">
  <div class="numero4">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_7">
  <div class="numero4">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_8">
  <div class="numero4">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_9">
  <div class="numero4">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_10">
  <div class="numero4">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_11">
  <div class="numero4">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_12">
  <div class="numero4">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_13">
  <div class="numero4">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_14">
  <div class="numero4">14</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_15">
  <div class="numero4">15</div>
</div>

<div id="layer5_1">
  <div class="numero5">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_2">
  <div class="numero5">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_3">
  <div class="numero5">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_4">
  <div class="numero5">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_5">
  <div class="numero5">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_6">
  <div class="numero5">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_7">
  <div class="numero5">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_8">
  <div class="numero5">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_9">
  <div class="numero5">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_10">
  <div class="numero5">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_11">
  <div class="numero5">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_12">
  <div class="numero5">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_13">
  <div class="numero5">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_14">
  <div class="numero5">14</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_15">
  <div class="numero5">15</div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo compruebo que estén visibles los dos primeros divs con "1".

Comment: Gracias Asier tu comprobación sí que funciona como debería! No entiendo por qué las otras no. Un saludo.

Comment: Pero por qué se repite el layer0 ? Es que no funciona bien... No entiendo cual es el error.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que se repite el layer0?

Comment: Sí Asier, me sale toda la primera secuencia de números repetida en la esquina superior izquierda cuando aplico el código.

Comment: Pero el problema tiene que estar en otra parte del código. Con este ejemplo no pasa.

Comment: Ya está resuelto, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{  
   if ($('#layer0_1').is(':visible')) 
   {
alert(new Date());
   }
    
});

function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo, inicial) {
  var $els = $('div[id^=' + selector + ']'),
      i = inicial,
      len = $els.length;

  $els.not( ':eq('+i+')' ).hide(); /*Ocultamos los que no sean el inicial */
  setInterval(function () {
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function () {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
   $("#layer6_").text($els.eq(i).attr('id'));
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
    if ($els.eq(i) === 1){
    alert('1');
     }
  }, tiempo)
}

jQuery(function() {
  /* Este sería el número que debería proporcionar el código del lado del servidor, 
   por ejemplo en PHP: round(microtime(true) * 1000)*/
   var startdate = " May 20 2016 21:49:57 GMT+0200  ", 
   timestamp =  new Date() - new Date(startdate) ;

  mostrarEsconder('layer0_', 300,  Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 11),
  mostrarEsconder('layer1_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 12),
  mostrarEsconder('layer2_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 13),
  mostrarEsconder('layer3_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 14),
  mostrarEsconder('layer4_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 15),
  mostrarEsconder('layer5_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 30);
});
```

```css
.numero {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  left: 20px;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  left: 20px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero3 {
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  left: 20px;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero4 {
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  left: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 500; }

.numero5 {
  position: absolute;
  color: cyan;
  left: 20px;
  top: 120px;
  z-index: 500; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer0_1">
<div class="numero">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_2">
<div class="numero">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_3">
<div class="numero">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_4">
<div class="numero">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_5">
<div class="numero">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_6">
<div class="numero">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_7">
<div class="numero">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_8">
<div class="numero">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_9">
<div class="numero">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_10">
<div class="numero">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_11">
<div class="numero">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_1">
<div class="numero1">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_2">
<div class="numero1">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_3">
<div class="numero1">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_4">
<div class="numero1">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_5">
<div class="numero1">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_6">
<div class="numero1">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_7">
<div class="numero1">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_8">
<div class="numero1">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_9">
<div class="numero1">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_10">
<div class="numero1">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_11">
<div class="numero1">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_12">
<div class="numero1">12</div>
</div>

<div id="layer2_1">
<div class="numero2">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_2">
<div class="numero2">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_3">
<div class="numero2">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_4">
<div class="numero2">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_5">
<div class="numero2">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_6">
<div class="numero2">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_7">
<div class="numero2">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_8">
<div class="numero2">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_9">
<div class="numero2">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_10">
<div class="numero2">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_11">
<div class="numero2">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_12">
<div class="numero2">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_13">
<div class="numero2">13</div>
</div>

<div id="layer3_1">
<div class="numero3">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_2">
<div class="numero3">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_3">
<div class="numero3">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_4">
<div class="numero3">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_5">
<div class="numero3">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_6">
<div class="numero3">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_7">
<div class="numero3">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_8">
<div class="numero3">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_9">
<div class="numero3">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_10">
<div class="numero3">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_11">
<div class="numero3">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_12">
<div class="numero3">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_13">
<div class="numero3">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_14">
<div class="numero3">14</div>
</div>

<div id="layer4_1">
<div class="numero4">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_2">
<div class="numero4">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_3">
<div class="numero4">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_4">
<div class="numero4">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_5">
<div class="numero4">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_6">
<div class="numero4">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_7">
<div class="numero4">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_8">
<div class="numero4">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_9">
<div class="numero4">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_10">
<div class="numero4">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_11">
<div class="numero4">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_12">
<div class="numero4">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_13">
<div class="numero4">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_14">
<div class="numero4">14</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_15">
<div class="numero4">15</div>
</div>

<div id="layer5_1">
<div class="numer5">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_2">
<div class="numer5">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_3">
<div class="numer5">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_4">
<div class="numer5">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_5">
<div class="numer5">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_6">
<div class="numer5">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_7">
<div class="numer5">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_8">
<div class="numer5">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_9">
<div class="numer5">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_10">
<div class="numer5">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_11">
<div class="numer5">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_12">
<div class="numer5">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_13">
<div class="numer5">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_14">
<div class="numer5">14</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_15">
<div class="numero5">15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, sigue haciendo lo mismo, ya probé esa opción. Además necesito que la alerta se muestre cuando todos coincidan en 1, aunque bueno no creo que eso fuera difícil cuando ya funcione para un solo div. Si te fijas la alerta sale nada más cargar la página y no debería.

Comment: y por que no pruebas haciendo un if, ya modifique el codigo. tu dime si asi quieres que funcione.

Comment: Qué va, no funciona, sigue saliendo la alerta cuando le doy a Ejecutar y no cuando el div  #layer0_1 es visible... no sé cual será el problema pero yo sospecho que puede estar relacionado con la forma de hacerlo aparecer (es un fadeIn) es muy raro que esto no funcione como debería...

Answer (score 0):

Solo compruebas si el `div` es visible al cargar la página, tienes que comprobarlo siempre que cambien los valores:

```js
function mostrarEsconder(selector, tiempo, inicial) {
  var $els = $('div[id^=' + selector + ']'),
    i = inicial,
    len = $els.length;

  $els.not(':eq(' + i + ')').hide(); /*Ocultamos los que no sean el inicial */
  setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#layer0_1').is(':visible')) {
      alert(new Date());
    }
    $els.eq(i).fadeOut(0, function() {
      i = (i + 1) % len;
      $("#layer6_").text($els.eq(i).attr('id'));
      $els.eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    })
    if ($els.eq(i) === 1) {
      alert('1');
    }
  }, tiempo)
}

jQuery(function() {
  /* Este sería el número que debería proporcionar el código del lado del servidor, 
   por ejemplo en PHP: round(microtime(true) * 1000)*/
  var startdate = " May 20 2016 21:49:57 GMT+0200  ",
    timestamp = new Date() - new Date(startdate);

  mostrarEsconder('layer0_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 11),
    mostrarEsconder('layer1_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 12),
    mostrarEsconder('layer2_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 13),
    mostrarEsconder('layer3_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 14),
    mostrarEsconder('layer4_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 15),
    mostrarEsconder('layer5_', 300, Math.floor(timestamp / 300) % 30);
});
```

```css
.numero {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 500;
}

.numero1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  left: 20px;
  top: 40px;
  z-index: 500;
}

.numero2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  left: 20px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 500;
}

.numero3 {
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  left: 20px;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 500;
}

.numero4 {
  position: absolute;
  color: orange;
  left: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 500;
}

.numero5 {
  position: absolute;
  color: cyan;
  left: 20px;
  top: 120px;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer0_1">
  <div class="numero">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_2">
  <div class="numero">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_3">
  <div class="numero">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_4">
  <div class="numero">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_5">
  <div class="numero">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_6">
  <div class="numero">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_7">
  <div class="numero">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_8">
  <div class="numero">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_9">
  <div class="numero">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_10">
  <div class="numero">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer0_11">
  <div class="numero">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_1">
  <div class="numero1">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_2">
  <div class="numero1">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_3">
  <div class="numero1">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_4">
  <div class="numero1">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_5">
  <div class="numero1">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_6">
  <div class="numero1">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_7">
  <div class="numero1">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_8">
  <div class="numero1">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_9">
  <div class="numero1">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_10">
  <div class="numero1">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_11">
  <div class="numero1">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer1_12">
  <div class="numero1">12</div>
</div>

<div id="layer2_1">
  <div class="numero2">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_2">
  <div class="numero2">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_3">
  <div class="numero2">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_4">
  <div class="numero2">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_5">
  <div class="numero2">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_6">
  <div class="numero2">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_7">
  <div class="numero2">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_8">
  <div class="numero2">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_9">
  <div class="numero2">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_10">
  <div class="numero2">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_11">
  <div class="numero2">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_12">
  <div class="numero2">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer2_13">
  <div class="numero2">13</div>
</div>

<div id="layer3_1">
  <div class="numero3">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_2">
  <div class="numero3">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_3">
  <div class="numero3">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_4">
  <div class="numero3">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_5">
  <div class="numero3">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_6">
  <div class="numero3">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_7">
  <div class="numero3">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_8">
  <div class="numero3">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_9">
  <div class="numero3">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_10">
  <div class="numero3">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_11">
  <div class="numero3">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_12">
  <div class="numero3">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_13">
  <div class="numero3">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer3_14">
  <div class="numero3">14</div>
</div>

<div id="layer4_1">
  <div class="numero4">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_2">
  <div class="numero4">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_3">
  <div class="numero4">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_4">
  <div class="numero4">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_5">
  <div class="numero4">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_6">
  <div class="numero4">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_7">
  <div class="numero4">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_8">
  <div class="numero4">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_9">
  <div class="numero4">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_10">
  <div class="numero4">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_11">
  <div class="numero4">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_12">
  <div class="numero4">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_13">
  <div class="numero4">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_14">
  <div class="numero4">14</div>
</div>
<div id="layer4_15">
  <div class="numero4">15</div>
</div>

<div id="layer5_1">
  <div class="numer5">1</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_2">
  <div class="numer5">2</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_3">
  <div class="numer5">3</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_4">
  <div class="numer5">4</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_5">
  <div class="numer5">5</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_6">
  <div class="numer5">6</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_7">
  <div class="numer5">7</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_8">
  <div class="numer5">8</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_9">
  <div class="numer5">9</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_10">
  <div class="numer5">10</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_11">
  <div class="numer5">11</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_12">
  <div class="numer5">12</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_13">
  <div class="numer5">13</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_14">
  <div class="numer5">14</div>
</div>
<div id="layer5_15">
  <div class="numero5">15</div>
</div>
```